# 120 outlet in an outdoor electrical cabinet

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor

I have an existing 110V outlet behind a weatherproof cover in my side yard, on the exterior wall. Above it the backyard patio company has installed a small metal outdoor electrical box (6”x12”x5”) that has a setup to convert bare wire to a 3 prong plug along with some fuse and a wireless controller for backyard lighting.

I would like to get a larger outdoor electrical cabinet (16”x16”x8”) to enclose both.  Is it okay to cut a single gang opening in a weatherproof electrical cabinet for the 110V outlet?  Does that violate code? Break best practice? Or alternate options that would work better?  Appreciate any help on this!

Current:
[image: Current:]

Wanted:
[image: Wanted:]

Thinking of using an enclosure similar to this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/VEVOR-2048-cu-in-Electrical-Enclosure-Box-16-x-16-x-8-in-NENA-4X-IP66-Junction-Outlet-Box-Fiberglass-with-Mounting-Plate-DQXFSBLG40X40X201V0/320686901#overlay

Comment: No, you do not have that `convert bare wire to a 3 prong plug`

Comment: By "bare wire" do you mean an (insulated) electrical cable?

Comment: Yes, poor choices of wording from me.  It's actually just regular extension cord type wiring.  I had remembered incorrectly when I wrote the question.